# Highmaps with two series but show one series on zoom in and another on zoom out

Tags: jquery, json, highmaps

I have a high map with two different series of Divisions and Sub divisions, both the series are showing on same time but i want to show one series at a time and another series on zooming in the map.

Thanks,

Comment: You can look at highmaps drilldown, but it's not clear what you ask for. Can you share you code with what you've tried so far? Maybe even make a jsfiddle showing what doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, drilldown is an option bur I want it on zooming in

Comment: Check the highmaps sample on the official website, find one similar to what you need, try it yourself and when you have an exact problem, share some code. Otherwise no one can actually help.